# Javascript producing random arrays with random numbers in it?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am doing a simple assignment for class, and am trying to create a table using just Javascript. I have my table perfectly set up, it's just that every other row it shows a random number, and then skips to the next. how can I get rid of the random row?

```
 var table = ["Name", "Turn Average", "Surface Area", "100% Boosting"];

 var names = ["Octane", "Dominus", "Breakout", "X-Devil", "Batmobile"];

 var turnaverages = [2.18, 2.22, 2.22, 2.21, 2.25];

 var surfacearea = [34495, 34529, 32679, 34242, 34365];

var maxboost = [1.967, 2.031, 2.035, 2.014, 2.10];

function info() {
document.write("<table>"); 
document.write("<tr>"); 

//these next lines output the table heading (th) tags for the table (this information doesn't repeat in the table)
document.write("<th>Name</th>");
document.write("<th>Turn Average</th>");
document.write("<th>Surface Area</th>");
document.write("<th>100% Boosting</th>");
document.write("</tr>"); //close first table row element
//create a for loop that will last for the number of days in the forecast
for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
    document.write("<tr>"); //create a table row
        //output each table data tag for the table with information pulled 
         from the arrays
        document.write("<td>" + names[i] + "</td>");
        document.write("<td>" + turnaverages[i] + "</td>");
        document.write("<td>" + surfacearea[i] + "</td>");
        document.write("<td>" + maxboost[i] + "</td>");
        document.write("</tr>");
        //depending on the description of the weather for the day, change 
           the image to be representative to that description -- (for 
           example on a rainy day, show the rainy image)
        if ( names[i] === "Dominus" ) {
            document.write("<td>" + turnaverages[i] + surfacearea[i] + 
            maxboost[i] + "</td>");
        }
        else if ( names[i] === "Breakout" ){
            document.write("<td>" + turnaverages[i] + surfacearea[i] + 
             maxboost[i] + "</td>");
        }
            else if ( names[i] === "X-Devil" ){
            document.write("<td>" + turnaverages[i] + surfacearea[i] + 
            maxboost[i] + "</td>");
        }
        else if( names[i] === "Batmobile" ){
            document.write("<td>" + turnaverages[i] + surfacearea[i] + 
            maxboost[i] + "</td>");

        }

       document.write("</tr>"); //close the table row element
     }
      document.write("</table>"); //close the table element
    }
```

Comment: document.wrong. Please use something more modern and less prone to doing confusing things. This function tries to write to the current document. If the document has already been processed, the document will be replaced with a blank one with your argument. You don't want that; use the proper DOM methods instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
document.write("<td>" + maxboost[i] + "</td>");
document.write("</tr>");
```

followed immediately by weather tests that attempt to write `td`s, followed again by another

```
document.write("</tr>"); //close the table row element
```

So, you just need to delete the first `</tr>`, since you don't actually want to close the row yet:

```js
var table = ["Name", "Turn Average", "Surface Area", "100% Boosting"];

var names = ["Octane", "Dominus", "Breakout", "X-Devil", "Batmobile"];

var turnaverages = [2.18, 2.22, 2.22, 2.21, 2.25];

var surfacearea = [34495, 34529, 32679, 34242, 34365];

var maxboost = [1.967, 2.031, 2.035, 2.014, 2.10];

function info() {
  document.write("<table>");
  document.write("<tr>");

  //these next lines output the table heading (th) tags for the table (this 
  document.write("<th>Name</th>");
  document.write("<th>Turn Average</th>");
  document.write("<th>Surface Area</th>");
  document.write("<th>100% Boosting</th>");
  document.write("</tr>"); //close first table row element
  //create a for loop that will last for the number of days in the forecast
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    document.write("<tr>"); //create a table row
    //output each table data tag for the table with information pulled 
    document.write("<td>" + names[i] + "</td>");
    document.write("<td>" + turnaverages[i] + "</td>");
    document.write("<td>" + surfacearea[i] + "</td>");
    document.write("<td>" + maxboost[i] + "</td>");
    //depending on the description of the weather for the day, change 
    if (names[i] === "Dominus") {
      document.write("<td>" + turnaverages[i] + surfacearea[i] +
        maxboost[i] + "</td>");
    } else if (names[i] === "Breakout") {
      document.write("<td>" + turnaverages[i] + surfacearea[i] +
        maxboost[i] + "</td>");
    } else if (names[i] === "X-Devil") {
      document.write("<td>" + turnaverages[i] + surfacearea[i] +
        maxboost[i] + "</td>");
    } else if (names[i] === "Batmobile") {
      document.write("<td>" + turnaverages[i] + surfacearea[i] +
        maxboost[i] + "</td>");

    }

    document.write("</tr>"); //close the table row element
  }
  document.write("</table>"); //close the table element
}
info();
```

The `2.22345292.031` and similar numbers are a result of string cocatenation - when you take a string and `+` to it, you will end up with another string. (not sure what you actually want there instead)